# multi-GNSS Positioning in android

Tags: android, gps

I am a PhD student in Electrical Engineering.

I have a question about positioning in phone. I'll be happy if answer to my question

I want the function (android command or java code or at least matlab code) of finding the Longitude, latitude and altitude of a location in smartphone when using multi-GNSS systems (GPS , GLONASS, BeiDou, Galileo).

In other words, how the geographical location is extracted in phones by receiving signals from multi-GNSS systems (GPS , GLONASS, BeiDou, Galileo)?Can you help me?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Comment: check wikipedia for gps, the calculation is explained there. But it is not very simple.

Comment: Here is a Research article ["A multiple GNSS-based orbit determination algorithm for geostationary satellites"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228867028_A_multiple_GNSS-based_orbit_determination_algorithm_for_geostationary_satellites).